# Why is my background image repeating about 1 pixel width, but is on no-repeat?

Tags: css, background-image

I'm replacing bullet points with puzzle pieces for a list. I'm adding them as background images. They are set to no-repeat.

For some reason, they are repeating about 1 pixel width on the bottom and right sides. I have no idea how to fix it. When I remove the "no-repeat" part of the background css, it still shows up this way.

Thanks ahead of time!

```
#menu-breakfast-lunch-sidebar-menu li.sidebarmenu_lunch {
background: url(http://url.wpengine.com/wp- 
content/uploads/2018/11/puzzlepiece_lunchmenu.jpg) no-repeat left top;
padding-left: 60px;
background-size: 50px;
padding-bottom: 25px;
background-position: 0% 0%;
}
```

Here is my example on CodePen: https://codepen.io/Clare12345/pen/pQjvWa

Screenshot
[image: Screenshot of icons]

Comment: Looks like a Chrome rendering bug. If you zoom in then back out, the artifacts disappear.

Comment: It's not the repeat, it's an issue with `background-size`

Comment: @fyroc I remember now! I used to know this but it's been a while. The browser can't shrink images perfectly always. I had to save the image as a more similar pixel width to what I intend to use it as. I did that and it's working now. Thank you!!! If you post an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a chrome rendering bug, specifically with the `background-size` attribute. If you resize the image to be smaller it will fix the issue and remove those unwanted pixels.

Here is also an article more details about the bug and other ways to fix the issue:

https://medium.com/@ryanjw/buggy-edges-in-chrome-when-using-background-size-cover-dd6eb44541fc

Answer (score 0):

I see you've got an answer to the render problem already but if you use the following css then you don't need to alter the base image size:

```
li.sidebarmenu_breakfast {
  background: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/djw6vunyp/image/upload/v1541519267/breakfastpuzzle.png) no-repeat left;
  background-size:contain;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  padding-left:50px;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

Give you more control over the styling of the list in general too.

Codepen example here - https://codepen.io/mattrey/pen/OayyLr

Hope this helps.